# Android:Checked Listview Item Goes at Last

Tags: android, listview

My ListView looks like this:

[CheckBox] [TextView]

My question is, how can I change the item position when CheckBox is checked? I mean to say, if the user checked any item from ListView, then the checked item goes to the end, so its position changes from current to last.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: post your adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom adapter for listView. here is an [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).  Now from your ListActivity class

```
final ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

    HashMap<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>)
    lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
   // get the item Position from here and make the nacessary changes
  // and update the listview again.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without posting any code, this will have to be a brief overview of the pseudo steps you need to take

You simply need to update the ordering of your data set being used by your adapter (usually an arraylist or array of objects), and then called

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

on your adapter.

So in your case, you want to take the element at the position that was clicked, and put it at the end of your arrayList of objects.

If you post some code, you may get more detailed answers however

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step you can follow. I have not tested it but you can try this.

```
// your value array you are binding with listview
private final String[] values;

// put default value to "n". size will be the same as for values array.
private final String[] valuesChecked; 


   onClick of Checkbox Listview



@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //get checkbox is checked or not
        if it is checked then{
            valuesChecked[position]="y";
        }else{
            valuesChecked[position]="n";
        }

        // short your values array by first "n" and after "y".
        // call your adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: Can you please upload the code after "if" condition in "onItemClick" method?

Comment: you mean sorting the array by "n" and "y"??

Comment: No. I done with it by Arrays.sort() method. But still not change in ListView. "MyItem planet = adapter.getItem(position);
  planet.toggleChecked();
  ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
  viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(planet.isSelected());

  Log.i("Checked::", "" + viewHolder.getCheckBox().isChecked());

  if (viewHolder.getCheckBox().isChecked()) {
   valuesChecked[position] = "y";
  } else {
   valuesChecked[position] = "n";
  }

  Arrays.sort(valuesChecked);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"

Comment: try to Log the sorting array and see that your array is getting sort or not?? And yes, one more thing is, in your getView method, you need to set checked = true for those position found "y" in array. :) i guess this is the problem that's why you are not getting checked value although it is already displaying sorting. let me know if you have still confusion.

Comment: Nope. Still i have same problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37178/discussion-between-lawrance-and-ripal-tamboli)